# Multiple Search Service Applications

Tags: 2010, search, enterprise-search

I see that it is possible to create multiple Search Service Applications. How can you get a Search Centre to use one Search Service Application over another.

Answer (score 2):

I found the option :)

Central Administration >  Application Management > Service Applications > Configure service application associations

You can change the service applications for a Web Application here.